# MySQLでSELECT時の並び順をFIELD以外で並び変える方法

Tags: mysql

MySQLの並び順に関して質問です。以下の様なデータがあるとします。

```
データ1
id,name,flag
1,鈴木,0
2,佐藤,1
3,佐々木,0
4,藤木,0

データ2
id,name,flag
1,鈴木,0
2,佐藤,0
3,佐々木,0
4,藤木,1
```

上記データをFIELD関数以外で以下の様に並び替えてSELECTする方法はありますでしょうか？

```
データ1
id,name,flag
2,佐藤,1
3,佐々木,0
4,藤木,0
1,鈴木,0

データ2
id,name,flag
4,藤木,1
1,鈴木,0
2,佐藤,0
3,佐々木,0
```

以上、宜しくお願い致します。

> > 追加コメント
> >     flagが1なのは必ず1レコードのみ。
> >     レコードの順番は必ず、idが1であれば、次のレコードが1、前のレコードがidの最大値になります。

Comment: 昇順降順以外の任意の順番でソートしたいということですよね？、Field関数を使わない方法だとCASE文でダラダラと書くしかないのでは？ソートのルールが分からないのでFIELD関数を使ったクエリを書くと伝わりやすいかもしれません。

Comment: コメント有難うございます。また、説明不足で申し訳ありません。ソートの順番は、輪っかみたいに、flagが1のレコードが先頭にきてそれ以外のレコードはレコードの前後の順番を守ってSELECTしたいと考えております。

Comment: `輪っかみたいに`が良くわからないんですが、`order by flag desc, id`で得られる結果とは違うんですよね？

Comment: flag が 1 のレコードは必ず一つだけ、ということでしょうか？

Comment: 任意の1レコード`flag=1`を先頭にして、対象ID以上のデータを昇順ソートし、末尾に到達したら先頭から対象IDまでを昇順ソートで結合するというイメージでしょうか？また、追加情報はコメントではなく質問文を編集して追記してください。コメントだと埋もれてしまいます。

Comment: あ、なるほど、そういうことか。@Myaku さんの言われてるので合ってる気がする。

Comment: はい、flagが1になるのは必ず1レコードになります。

Comment: union を使って、`(select * from tbl where id >= (select id from tbl where flag = 1) order by id)
union
(select * from tbl where id < (select id from tbl where flag = 1) order by id);` とでもしますかね。もっとキレイな書き方があると思いますが。

Comment: ぱっと確認できるmysql環境が無くて確認できないんですけど...`union`で並び順保証されましたっけ？

Comment: 以下の様にunionすれば、select出来るようになりましたｍｍ( 
  select
    * 
  from
    tbl 
  where
    flag = 1
) 
union
( 
  select
    * 
  from
    tbl 
  where
    id > (select id from tbl where flag = 1) 
  order by
    id
) 
union ( 
  select
    * 
  from
    tbl 
  where
    id < (select id from tbl where flag = 1) 
  order by
    id
)

Comment: @豚吐露 おっと、マニュアルを眺めると「保証しない」って書いてありますね。

Comment: @豚吐露 ＠metropolis 自分も同じように書いてました。0、1の定数カラムを追加して、結合後にソートかけるのが良いですかね？

Comment: @Myaku はい、それが確実ですね。[Using union and order by clause in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3531301)

Comment: UNIONってSELECT結果の結合なので、UNION SELECT内のでORDER BYしてれば問題ない様な気がするのですがどうでしょうか。

Comment: @LeoS [MySQL 5.6 リファレンスマニュアル :: 13.2.9.4 UNION 構文](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/union.html) には「ORDER BY が SELECT 内に LIMIT なしで現れた場合、この句はいずれにしても何も効果がないため、最適化によって削除されます。 」と書かれています。今回の場合で limit は使えないので、Myaku さんの言う「定数カラムの追加」が確実かと思います。

Comment: 有難うございます。なるほどです。色々と勉強不足で申し訳ありません。各SELECTステートメントに定数を定義してソートしてやります。大変助かりました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

環境無いのでクエリだけ組みました。
基準となるIDを副問い合わせしてUNIONで結合すればいいのかなぁと
**追記**：`UNION`句ではソート順序を保障されません。定数カラムを追加しソートしなおすことが必要です。

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT id
         , name
         , flag
         , (SELECT id FROM tableName WHERE flag = 1) AS target
         , 1 AS rank
    FROM tableName
    WHERE target<=id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id
         , name
         , flag
         , (SELECT id FROM tableName WHERE flag = 1) AS target
         , 2 AS rank
    FROM tableName
    WHERE target>id
) a
ORDER BY rank, id
```

---

**コメントのやり取りを追記**
※`UNION`句を使用した場合に`ORDER BY`を使用する場合について
[Using union and order by clause in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531251)
※MySQLリファレンス
[MySQL 5.6 リファレンスマニュアル :: 13.2.9.4 UNION 構文](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/union.html)

Comment: 有難うございます！大変助かりましたｍｍ

Answer (score 1):

クエリだけを検証したい人のために、 @Myaku さんの回答を CTE を用いてどこでも利用できるようにすると次です。 MySQL 8.0 以上で実行可能です。

```
with datas(id, name, flag) as (
  select 1, '鈴木' , 0
  union all
  select 2, '佐藤', 1
  union all
  select 3, '佐々木', 0
  union all
  select 4, '藤木', 0
), flagged as (
  select * from datas where flag = 1
), ranked(id, name, flag, `rank`) as (
  select *, 1 from datas where id >= (select id from flagged)
  union all
  select *, 2 from datas where id < (select id from flagged)
) 
select id, name, flag from ranked order by `rank`, id;
```

---

### 追記

上を用いて explain をいくつか叩いてみた結果、 MySQL においてはこれが一番良さそうだ、という結論になりました。

```
with
datas(id, name, flag) as (
  select 1, '鈴木' , 0
  union all
  select 2, '佐藤', 1
  union all
  select 3, '佐々木', 0
  union all
  select 4, '藤木', 0
)
select id, name, flag from (
  select datas.*,
         case when id >= (select id from datas where flag = 1)
           then 1
           else 2
         end as `rank`
  from datas 
) as ranked
order by `rank`, id;
```

#### 理由:

- subquery (`select id from datas where flag = 1`) の実行を確実に1回に絞ることができる
- MySQL においては UNION ALL の結果テーブルを一度計算しておかねばならず、なのでテーブルの全走査は少なくとも1回は必要